# MojangAPI Limit Request

Tags: php, api, minecraft

I'm using [MineTheCube's MojangAPI PHP](https://github.com/MineTheCube/MojangAPI/blob/master/mojang-api.class.php) and i did 1,600 requests in ~10 minutes. Does the MojangAPI have a limit on request? I ask because I'm trying to request it now and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the php api is a wrapper, it probably shares the limit with the offical mojang api.

> All public APIs are rate limited so you are expected to cache the results. This is currently set at 600 requests per 10 minutes but this may change.

(http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API)